# Laravel 7 - Return Parent Menus

Tags: php, laravel

i 'm creating a menu level from database , my database looks like :

ID | NAME | PARENT_ID |

on App/Models/Menu i have created a function that i wanna retrieve the submenus , looks like

```
 public function submenus()
{


    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menu', 'parent_id','id')->orderBy('name');
    
}
```

and another to return the parents

```
public function parents()
{


    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menu', 'parent_id','id')->orderBy('name');
    
}
```

to create my menu dynamic i am using this on controller :

```
$menus = \App\Models\Menu::whereIn('parent_id',NULL)->with('submenus')->get();
```

that works fine , because i receive the MenuParent with your submenus relationed .

But how could i only receive the Parents , without put "with" , i just wanna receive the parents.

i tried put this on my controller :

```
$menu_parent = Menu::parents()->get();
```

but i receive the error :

ErrorException
Non-static method App\Models\Menu::parents() should not be called statically

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do

```
$parent = Menu::where('parent_id',NULL)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `parents()->get()` form will only work on a model instance (model object), not on a class. Like that:

```
$myModel = Menu::first();
$parents = $myModel->parents()->get();
// now $parents is a collection of parents of $myModel
```